# How to cross-link ("wikify") lines in different files with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed

I have files with one-line notes that contain links to other notes in
the form of `>filename_without_extension:line_nr`:

```
m01.txt:
Line 1. >m02:2
Line 2. >m02:3
Line 3.

m02.txt:
Line 1.
Line 2. >m01:3
Line 3. >m01:1 >m01:3
```

I want to add automatic wiki-like "backlinks" to every linked line that
doesn't yet have them. So the desired output should be like this:

```
m01.txt:
Line 1. >m02:2 >m02:3
Line 2. >m02:3
Line 3. >m02:3 >m02:2

m02.txt:
Line 1.
Line 2. >m01:3 >m01:1
Line 3. >m01:1 >m01:3 >m01:2
```

I came up with something quite awful and non-working for *sed*. It should walk through all files in my notes directory:

```
link_regex=$(sed -e '/(\>m[0-9]+\:[0-9]+?)+?/p')
linenr_from_link_regex=$(sed -e '/\>m[0-9]+?\:/d')
fname_from_cur_link=$(sed -e '/\:[0-9]+?\b/d;/\.txt/a')
link_from_f=$(sed -e '/^/\>/g;/\.txt$/d;/\:=/a' < "$f")
new_link_to_cur_f=$(sed -i "${linenr_fom_cur_link}a\ ${link_from_f}" ${fname_from_cur_link})

function create-cross-references () {
    while read line; do
        echo "$link_regex" | \          # look up links 
        echo "$linenr_from_link_regex"      # pipe to get line number from current link 
        echo "$fname_from_cur_link"         # turn current link to new file name
        echo "$link_from_f"                 # turn current file name name to new link
        echo "$new_link_to_cur_f"           # add new link to current fname
    done
}

for f in *.txt; do
    create-cross-references
done
```

Where am I going wrong here? Also, what's a more reasonable solution (preferably still using *sed*) that avoids stepping through all the lines (including those without links) in
my notes folder every single time? Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you post a desired output? I mean the m01 and m02 after the processing. and if an item in m01 was linked by 7 files, how would you handle this case? how do you decide, which file should "back" to?

Comment: I added the output. I guess "backlinks" aren't quite correct here; they're rather cross-linked items. If item 1 in file 1 has a link to item 2 in file 2, then item 2 in file 2 should also get a link to item 1 in file 1. If an item has 7 links, they're just listed and following the item (line) one after another. Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: I don't think you can save commands in variables the way you've done in your example. `var=$(command)` saves the **output** of `command` to `var`.

Comment: @whereswalden Yes, I wasn't sure of this either. And it didn't work, so you're probably right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getlinks() {
    # $1 must be something like >m01:1
    grep "$1" *.txt | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\):Line \([0-9]\+\)..*/>\1:\3 /' | \
    # all matches in one single line
    tr -d '\n'
}
for fileName in *.txt;do
    echo "$fileName:"
    while read line;do
        #Line 1. whatever ==> 1
        lineNumber=$( echo $line | grep -Po '(?<=(Line )).*(?=\.)' )
        #m01.txt ==> >m01
        fileNameFormatted=$( echo "$fileName" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\..*/>\1/'  )
        links=$( getlinks "$fileNameFormatted:$lineNumber" )
        echo "$line $links"
    done < $fileName
done
```

Output:

```
m01.txt:
Line 1. >m02:2 >m02:3 
Line 2. >m02:3 
Line 3. >m02:2 >m02:3 
m02.txt:
Line 1. 
Line 2. >m01:3 >m01:1 
Line 3. >m01:1 >m01:3 >m01:2
```

EDIT: Due to @martt's comment,

> [...] Can you please remove the Line 1.  prefix from the regex? The
>   lines actually contain just random text + the link (as in `Blablalbla. >m01:1`; it was a misleading example from me). Also, how do I echo the changes to the real files?

I've made some changes to the original script.

1. The line number it's not present in the text file, so a variable is needed. (`$lineNumber`)
2. If the script is run multiple times, The *cross-links* would be duplicated, so it is necessary to avoid that.
3. The result must be stored in the same file.

---

```
#!/bin/bash


for fileName in *.txt;do
    #"Line 1" it is not present now. We've to carry the count of lines processed
    let lineNumber=1
    while read line;do 
        # transform m01.txt into >m01
        fileNameFormatted=$( echo "$fileName" | sed -E 's/(.*)\..*/>\1/'  )
        links=$( \
        #search for occurrences of >filename : grep -nr will return something like
        # m02.txt:3:whatever. >m01:1 >m01:3
        # in this example,
        # we take the filename (m02) and the line number (3).
        # adding '>' and ':'. Result: >m02:3
        grep -nr "$fileNameFormatted:$lineNumber" *.txt  | \
        sed -E 's/(.*)\.(.*):([0-9]+):(.*).(.*)/>\1:\3/' | \
        # replace new lines with spaces
        tr '\n' ' ')
        # skipping duplicates :
        links=$( \
        #merge existing line with links found
        echo "$line $links" | \
        #strip all before the dot
        sed -E 's/(.*)\.(.*)/\2/' | \
        # replace spaces with new line
        tr ' ' '\n' | \
        # remove duplicates: >m02:2 >m02:2 >m03:3
        # ==> >m02:2 >m03:3
        sort -u | \
        # replace newlines with spaces.
        tr '\n' ' ')
        # remove all before the last dot: 
        # Line 1. >m02:2 >m03:3 ==> Line 1
        line=$(echo $line | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/')
        #merge both strings and append them to a temporary file
        echo "$line.$links" >> "$fileName.tmp"
        let lineNumber++
    done < "$fileName"
        #replace the original file
        mv "$fileName.tmp" "$fileName"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please remove the `Line 1. `  prefix from the regex? The lines actually contain just random text + the link (as in `Blablalbla. >m01:1`; it was a misleading example from me). Also, how do I echo the changes to the real files?

Comment: @marttt I'm not at the computer right now. Do you mind if I do this in a couple of hours? If you are in a hurry maybe in an hour.

Comment: sure, I'm not in a hurry at all, take your time! I tried to do it myself, but I'm a complete amateur and the regex is fairly complex, etc. Thanks again!

Comment: @marttt changes done! . I've added more explanations, so you can understand the code better.

Comment: Brilliant, now it does what needed and more (I thought I'd figure out a separate function for removing link duplicates, but now you did it for me :). Also, your comments are really valuable and helpful, so it's an excellent answer. Thanks very much again!